# Java8 how to get list of objects based on the value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Code is here
order is having shipment and shipment having items and items having product

***Order Class
----------------***

```
public class Order {

    private List<Shipment> shipment;

    public List<Shipment> getShipment() {
        return shipment;
    }

    public void setShipment(List<Shipment> shipment) {
        this.shipment = shipment;
    }
    
}
```

**Shipment Class***

```
public class Shipment {
    
    private List<Item> item;
    
    public List<Item> getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    
    public void setItem(List<Item> item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    
}
```

**Item Class**

```
public class Item {

    private Product product;

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
    
    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
    
}
```

**Product**

```
 public class Product {
    
        private String name;
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        
    }

    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
    List<Shipment> shipmentList = new ArrayList<Shipment>();
    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    
    Shipment shipment = new Shipment();
    shipment.setItem(itemList);
    shipmentList.add(shipment);
    
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setShipment(shipmentList);
    orderList.add(order);
    
    Item item1 = new Item();
    Item item2 = new Item();
    Item item3 = new Item();
    Item item4 = new Item();
    Item item5 = new Item();
    Item item6 = new Item();
    Item item7 = new Item();
    
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("Mobile");
    Product product1 = new Product();
    product1.setName("Mobile");
    Product product2 = new Product();
    product2.setName("Tv");
    Product product3 = new Product();
    product3.setName("AC");
    Product product4 = new Product();
    product4.setName("Tab");
    Product product5 = new Product();
    product5.setName("Bike");
    Product product6 = new Product();
    product6.setName("Bike");
    Product product7 = new Product();
    product7.setName("Bike");
    
    item1.setProduct(product);
    item1.setProduct(product1);
    item2.setProduct(product2);
    item3.setProduct(product3);
    item4.setProduct(product4);
    item5.setProduct(product5);
    item6.setProduct(product7);
    item7.setProduct(product7);
  
    itemList.add(item1);
    itemList.add(item2);
    itemList.add(item3);
    itemList.add(item4);
    itemList.add(item5);
    itemList.add(item6);
    itemList.add(item7);
```

Here want to pass product name like mobile in to a  method that return list of order which matches product name mobile..
Could you please help how we can right using streams in java8

Comment: have you tried something so far?

Comment: No.. we have to get Product Class and product name and compare with input productName say Mobile
using like orderList.stream()......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be better to use `flatMap` for the inner lists:

```java
List<Order> filteredOrders = orderList
        .stream()
        .filter(o -> o.getShipment().stream()
            .flatMap(s -> s.getItem().stream()) // stream of Item
            .map(Item::getProduct) // stream of products
            .map(Product:getName)  // stream of product names
            .anyMatch("Mobile"::equals)
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/aSWJL4)

The chain of method `map` with method references may be replaced with a simple `anyMatch`:

```java
List<Order> filteredOrders = orderList.stream()
        .filter(o -> o.getShipment().stream()
                .flatMap(s -> s.getItem().stream()) // stream of Item
                .anyMatch(i -> "Mobile".equals(i.getProduct().getName()))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**Update**

If the filtered orders must contain only the shipments with filtered items, this implies that the entire chain of objects and their containers needs to be  recreated:

new Order with new list of Shipment -> new Shipment with new list of Items -> new Item with a copy of Product from the matching product (with "Mobile" name).

Assuming that all the relevant constructors have been provided, the orders with the filtered products may look as follows:

```java
List<Order> filteredOrderProducts = orderList
        .stream()
        .filter(o -> // same filter as before
                o.getShipment().stream()
                               .flatMap(s -> s.getItem().stream()) // stream of Item
                               .anyMatch(i -> "Mobile".equals(i.getProduct().getName()))
        )
        .map(o -> new Order(
                o.getShipment().stream()
                               .map(s -> new Shipment(
                                       s.getItem().stream()
                                                  .filter(i -> "Mobile".equals(i.getProduct().getName()))
                                                  .map(i -> new Item(i)) // copy constructor
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toList())
                               )) // new Shipment(List<Item> items)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )) // new Order(List<Shipment> shipments)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
System.out.println("----\norders with filtered products");
filteredOrderProducts.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
----
orders with filtered products
order: shipments=[items=[:product=product.name=Mobile]]
order: shipments=[items=[:product=product.name=Mobile]]
```

[Updated online demo](https://ideone.com/kz3bkN)

Comment: I tried the above login.. but it will give all products including producting tv, tab ..
we want to collect product type  Mobile orders only.. 
Oupput:- [Order [shipment=[Shipment [item=[Item [product=Product [name=Mobile]], Item [product=Product [name=Tv]], Item [product=Product [name=AC]], Item [product=Product [name=Tab]], Item [product=Product [name=WashingMaching]], Item [product=Product [name=WashingMaching]], Item [product=Product [name=WashingMaching]]]]]]]

Comment: @Raju, in your setup one order contains multiple products.  If `orderList` contains an order _without_ mobile product, it won't be included.  You should check the [demo link](https://ideone.com/aSWJL4) -- I set up 3 orders and only 2 of them have "Mobile" product, which are returned in the `filteredOrders` list.

Comment: @Raju, you may check the updated answer, and you should edit your question to add your comment.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood . got it ..

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you describe

```
List<Order> filteredList = orderList.stream().filter( order1 -> {
    return order1.getShipment().stream().anyMatch( shipment1 -> {
        return shipment1.getItem().stream().anyMatch( item -> {
            return item.getProduct().getName().equals("Mobile");
        });
    });
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```